# Problema con relleno select boxes en HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código en javascript para llenar 3 select dependiendo de la región y provincia seleccionadas.

```js
var RegionesYcomunas = {
  "regiones": [{
    "NombreRegion": "Region de Tarapacá",
    "provincias": ["Iquique", "Tamarugal"],
    "comunas": ["Iquique", "Alto Hospicio", "Pozo Almonte", "Camiña", "Colchane", "Huara", "Pica"]
  },
  {
    "NombreRegion": "Region de Antofagasta",
    "provincias": ["Antofagasta", "El Loa", "Tocopilla"],
    "comunas": ["Antofagasta", "Mejillones", "Sierra Gorda", "Taltal", "Calama", "Ollagüe", "San Pedro de Atacama", "Tocopilla", "María Elena"]
  },
  {
    "NombreRegion": "Region de Atacama",
    "provincias": ["Chañaral", "Copiapó", "Huasco"],
    "comunas": ["Copiapó", "Caldera", "Tierra Amarilla", "Chañaral", "Diego de Almagro", "Vallenar", "Alto del Carmen", "Freirina", "Huasco"]
  },
  {
    "NombreRegion": "Region de Coquimbo",
    "provincias":["Choapa", "Elqui", "Limarí"],
    "comunas": ["La Serena", "Coquimbo", "Andacollo", "La Higuera", "Paiguano", "Vicuña", "Illapel", "Canela", "Los Vilos", "Salamanca", "Ovalle", "Combarbalá", "Monte Patria", "Punitaqui", "Río Hurtado"]
  },
  {
    "NombreRegion": "Region de Valparaíso",
    "provincias":["Isla de Pascua", "Los Andes", "Marga Marga", "Petorca", "Quillota", "San Antonio", "San Felipe de Aconcagua", "Valparaíso"],
    "comunas": ["Valparaíso", "Casablanca", "Concón", "Juan Fernández", "Puchuncaví", "Quintero", "Viña del Mar", "Isla de Pascua", "Los Andes", "Calle Larga", "Rinconada", "San Esteban", "La Ligua", "Cabildo", "Papudo", "Petorca", "Zapallar", "Quillota", "Calera", "Hijuelas", "La Cruz", "Nogales", "San Antonio", "Algarrobo", "Cartagena", "El Quisco", "El Tabo", "Santo Domingo", "San Felipe", "Catemu", "Llaillay", "Panquehue", "Putaendo", "Santa María", "Quilpué", "Limache", "Olmué", "Villa Alemana"]
  },
  {
    "NombreRegion": "Región del Libertador Gral. Bernardo O’Higgins",
    "provincias":["Chachapoal", "Cardenal Caro", "Colchagua"],
    "comunas": ["Rancagua", "Codegua", "Coinco", "Coltauco", "Doñihue", "Graneros", "Las Cabras", "Machalí", "Malloa", "Mostazal", "Olivar", "Peumo", "Pichidegua", "Quinta de Tilcoco", "Rengo", "Requínoa", "San Vicente", "Pichilemu", "La Estrella", "Litueche", "Marchihue", "Navidad", "Paredones", "San Fernando", "Chépica", "Chimbarongo", "Lolol", "Nancagua", "Palmilla", "Peralillo", "Placilla", "Pumanque", "Santa Cruz"]
  },
  {
    "NombreRegion": "Región del Maule",
    "provincias":["Cauquenes", "Curicó", "Linares", "Talca"],
    "comunas": ["Talca", "ConsVtución", "Curepto", "Empedrado", "Maule", "Pelarco", "Pencahue", "Río Claro", "San Clemente", "San Rafael", "Cauquenes", "Chanco", "Pelluhue", "Curicó", "Hualañé", "Licantén", "Molina", "Rauco", "Romeral", "Sagrada Familia", "Teno", "Vichuquén", "Linares", "Colbún", "Longaví", "Parral", "ReVro", "San Javier", "Villa Alegre", "Yerbas Buenas"]
    },
    {
    "NombreRegion": "Región del Biobío",
    "provincias":["Arauco", "Biobío", "Concepción"],
    "comunas": ["Concepción", "Coronel", "Chiguayante", "Florida", "Hualqui", "Lota", "Penco", "San Pedro de la Paz", "Santa Juana", "Talcahuano", "Tomé", "Hualpén", "Lebu", "Arauco", "Cañete", "Contulmo", "Curanilahue", "Los Álamos", "Tirúa", "Los Ángeles", "Antuco", "Cabrero", "Laja", "Mulchén", "Nacimiento", "Negrete", "Quilaco", "Quilleco", "San Rosendo", "Santa Bárbara", "Tucapel", "Yumbel", "Alto Biobío", "Cobquecura", "Coelemu", "Ninhue", "Portezuelo", "Quirihue", "Ránquil", "Treguaco"]
  },
  {
    "NombreRegion": "Región de la Araucanía",
    "provincias":["Cautín", "Malleco"],
    "comunas": ["Temuco", "Carahue", "Cunco", "Curarrehue", "Freire", "Galvarino", "Gorbea", "Lautaro", "Loncoche", "Melipeuco", "Nueva Imperial", "Padre las Casas", "Perquenco", "Pitrufquén", "Pucón", "Saavedra", "Teodoro Schmidt", "Toltén", "Vilcún", "Villarrica", "Cholchol", "Angol", "Collipulli", "Curacautín", "Ercilla", "Lonquimay", "Los Sauces", "Lumaco", "Purén", "Renaico", "Traiguén", "Victoria", ]
  },
  {
    "NombreRegion": "Región de Los Lagos",
    "provincias":["Chiloé", "Llanquihue", "Osorno", "Palena"],
    "comunas": ["Puerto Montt", "Calbuco", "Cochamó", "Fresia", "FruVllar", "Los Muermos", "Llanquihue", "Maullín", "Puerto Varas", "Castro", "Ancud", "Chonchi", "Curaco de Vélez", "Dalcahue", "Puqueldón", "Queilén", "Quellón", "Quemchi", "Quinchao", "Osorno", "Puerto Octay", "Purranque", "Puyehue", "Río Negro", "San Juan de la Costa", "San Pablo", "Chaitén", "Futaleufú", "Hualaihué", "Palena"]
  },
  {
    "NombreRegion": "Región Aysén del Gral. Carlos Ibáñez del Campo",
    "provincias":["Aysén", "Capitán Prat", "Coyhaique", "General Carrera"],
    "comunas": ["Coihaique", "Lago Verde", "Aisén", "Cisnes", "Guaitecas", "Cochrane", "O’Higgins", "Tortel", "Chile Chico", "Río Ibáñez"]
  },
  {
    "NombreRegion": "Región de Magallanes y de la Antártica Chilena",
    "provincias":["Antártica Chilena", "Magallanes", "Tierra del Fuego", "Última Esperanza"],
    "comunas": ["Punta Arenas", "Laguna Blanca", "Río Verde", "San Gregorio", "Cabo de Hornos (Ex Navarino)", "Antártica", "Porvenir", "Primavera", "Timaukel", "Natales", "Torres del Paine"]
  },
  {
    "NombreRegion": "Región Metropolitana de Santiago",
    "provincias":["Chacabuco", "Cordillera", "Maipo", "Melipilla", "Santiago", "Talagante"],
    "comunas": ["Cerrillos", "Cerro Navia", "Conchalí", "El Bosque", "Estación Central", "Huechuraba", "Independencia", "La Cisterna", "La Florida", "La Granja", "La Pintana", "La Reina", "Las Condes", "Lo Barnechea", "Lo Espejo", "Lo Prado", "Macul", "Maipú", "Ñuñoa", "Pedro Aguirre Cerda", "Peñalolén", "Providencia", "Pudahuel", "Quilicura", "Quinta Normal", "Recoleta", "Renca", "San Joaquín", "San Miguel", "San Ramón", "Vitacura", "Puente Alto", "Pirque", "San José de Maipo", "Colina", "Lampa", "TilVl", "San Bernardo", "Buin", "Calera de Tango", "Paine", "Melipilla", "Alhué", "Curacaví", "María Pinto", "San Pedro", "Talagante", "El Monte", "Isla de Maipo", "Padre Hurtado", "Peñaflor"]
  },
  {
    "NombreRegion": "Región de Los Ríos",
    "provincias":["Ranco", "Valdivia"],
    "comunas": ["Valdivia", "Corral", "Lanco", "Los Lagos", "Máfil", "Mariquina", "Paillaco", "Panguipulli", "La Unión", "Futrono", "Lago Ranco", "Río Bueno"]
  },
  {
    "NombreRegion": "Region de Arica y Parinacota",
    "provincias": ["Arica", "Parinacota"],
    "comunas": ["Arica", "Camarones", "Putre", "Parinacota","General Lagos"]
  },
  {
    "NombreRegion": "Región de Ñuble",
    "provincias":["Diguillín", "Itata", "Punilla"],
    "comunas": ["Bulnes", "Chillán", "Chillán Viejo", "El Carmen", "Pemuco", "Pinto", "Quillón", "San Ignacio", "Yungay", "San Carlos", "Coihueco", "Ñiquén", "San Fabián", "San Nicolás"]
            
  }]
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

  var iRegion = 0;
            
  var htmlRegion = '<option value=" ">Seleccione región</option><option value=" " disabled="disabled">--</option>';
  var htmlProvincias = '<option value=" ">Seleccione una provincia</option><option value=" " disabled="disabled">--</option>';

  var htmlComunas = '<option value=" ">Seleccione una comuna</option><option value=" " disabled="disabled">--</option>';

  jQuery.each(RegionesYcomunas.regiones, function () {
    htmlRegion = htmlRegion + '<option value="' + RegionesYcomunas.regiones[iRegion].NombreRegion + '">' + RegionesYcomunas.regiones[iRegion].NombreRegion + '</option>';
    iRegion++;
  });

  jQuery('#regiones').html(htmlRegion);
    jQuery('#provincias').html(htmlProvincias);
    jQuery('#comunas').html(htmlComunas);

    jQuery('#regiones').change(function () {
      var iRegiones = 0;
      var valorRegion = jQuery(this).val();

      var htmlProvincia = '<option value=" ">Seleccione provincia</option><option value="sin-provincia" disabled="disabled">--</option>';
                
      jQuery.each(RegionesYcomunas.regiones, function () {
        if (RegionesYcomunas.regiones[iRegiones].NombreRegion == valorRegion) {
                        
          var iProvincias = 0;
          jQuery.each(RegionesYcomunas.regiones[iRegiones].provincias, function () {
                            
            htmlProvincia = htmlProvincia + '<option value="' + RegionesYcomunas.regiones[iRegiones].provincias[iProvincias] + '">' + RegionesYcomunas.regiones[iRegiones].provincias[iProvincias] + '</option>';
            iProvincias++;
        });
      }
      iRegiones++;
    });
    jQuery('#provincias').html(htmlProvincia);
  });

  jQuery('#provincias').change(function(){

    valorProvincia = jQuery(this).val();
    var htmlComuna = '<option value=" ">Seleccione una comuna</option><option value="sin-comuna" disabled="disabled">--</option>';
    var iComunas = 0;

    jQuery.each(RegionesYcomunas.provincias, function(){
      if (RegionesYcomunas.regiones[iProvincias].provincias == valorProvincia) {
        jQuery.each(RegionesYcomunas.regiones[iRegiones].comunas, function(){
          htmlComuna = htmlComuna + '<option value="' + RegionesYcomunas.regiones[iRegiones].comunas[iComunas] + '">' + RegionesYcomunas.regiones[iRegiones].comunas[iComunas] + '</option>';
          iComunas++;
        });
      }
      iProvincias++;
    });
    jQuery('#comunas').html(htmlComuna);
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Dekko';
  -webkit-user-select: none !important;
  -moz-user-select: none !important;
  -o-user-select: none !important;
  -ms-user-select: none !important;
}
select{
  font-family: 'Dekko';
  font-size: 12pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dekko" rel="stylesheet">

<body oncontextmenu="return false">
<h3>Seleccione</h3>
<select id="regiones" class="select_region" required="required" name="regiones"></select>
<br><br>
<select id="provincias" class="select_provincia" required="required" name="provincias"></select>
<br><br>
<select id="comunas" class="select_ciudad" required="required" name="comunas"></select>
</body>
```

Resulta que el `<select>` para mostrar las comunas no funciona, no muestra nada luego de seleccionar una provincia.

**Mi problema es** que, lo que **debería hacer** cuando seleccione una provincia, el **select de las comunas** debe mostrar las comunas correspondientes a la provincia escogida.

Para que no tengan que leer el código completo dejo la parte donde intento llenar el select de las comunas.

```
jQuery('#provincias').change(function(){

    valorProvincia = jQuery(this).val();
    var htmlComuna = '<option value=" ">Seleccione una comuna</option><option value="sin-comuna" disabled="disabled">--</option>';
    var iComunas = 0;

    jQuery.each(RegionesYcomunas.provincias, function(){
        if (RegionesYcomunas.regiones[iProvincias].provincias == valorProvincia) {
            jQuery.each(RegionesYcomunas.regiones[iRegiones].comunas, function(){
                htmlComuna = htmlComuna + '<option value="' + RegionesYcomunas.regiones[iRegiones].comunas[iComunas] + '">' + RegionesYcomunas.regiones[iRegiones].comunas[iComunas] + '</option>';
                iComunas++;
            });
        }
        iProvincias++;
    });
    jQuery('#comunas').html(htmlComuna);
});
```

Como dato extra este código lo obtuve de la siguiente fuente:
[Regiones y Comunas de Chile](https://codepen.io/sergiohidalgo/pen/yNjdqg)

Comment: Como vas a saber que comunas perteneces a que provincia?

Comment: Es lo que estaba intentando lograr, sin obtener el resultado que mencioné.

Comment: Creo que ese es el primer problema que tienes que resolver.  En el caso de region no hay problema porque cada objeto tiene una sola region.  Pero en el caso de provincia, no se puede diferenciar porque hay mas de una en cada objeto.  Te sugiero que talvez tengas otro array con las provincias y sus respectivas comunas, o quizas agregar otro nivel a tu array actual.

Comment: Entiendo a que te refieres, se me ocurrió una idea. Por otro lado con respecto a lo que publiqué que era lo que estaba intentando , que me sugieres?

Comment: Lo que estas intentado es imposible con el array que tienes actualmente.  Si lo que quieres es simplemente rellenar el select de comunas dependiendo del valor de la region, entonces si se podria hacer de la misma forma que hiciste con las provincias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El estado actual de tu JSON imposibilita conocer a qué provincia pertenece cada comuna, porque las mismas vienen en un array sin ningún identificador.

Una posibilidad sería construir un JSON donde tengas una clave por cada provincia y dentro de ella un array con sus respectivas comunas.

Sería una estructura como  esta:

```
{
  "regiones":[
    {
      "NombreRegion":"Region de Tarapacá",
      "provincias":[
        {
          "Iquique":[
            "Iquique",
            "Alto Hospicio",
            "Pozo Almonte"
          ]
        },
        {
          "Tamarugal":[
            "Camiña",
            "Colchane",
            "Huara",
            "Pica"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "NombreRegion":"Region de Antofagasta",
      "provincias":[
        {
          "Antofagasta":[
            "Antofagasta",
            "Mejillones",
            "Sierra Gorda"
          ]
        },
        {
          "El Loa":[
            "Taltal",
            "Calama",
            "Ollagüe"
          ]
        },
        {
          "Tocopilla":[
            "San Pedro de Atacama",
            "Tocopilla",
            "María Elena"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Los `select` dependientes podrían entonces realizarse sin problemas del modo siguiente:

```js
var str =
  `
{
  "regiones":[
    {
      "NombreRegion":"Region de Tarapacá",
      "provincias":[
        {
          "Iquique":[
            "Iquique",
            "Alto Hospicio",
            "Pozo Almonte"
          ]
        },
        {
          "Tamarugal":[
            "Camiña",
            "Colchane",
            "Huara",
            "Pica"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "NombreRegion":"Region de Antofagasta",
      "provincias":[
        {
          "Antofagasta":[
            "Antofagasta",
            "Mejillones",
            "Sierra Gorda"
          ]
        },
        {
          "El Loa":[
            "Taltal",
            "Calama",
            "Ollagüe"
          ]
        },
        {
          "Tocopilla":[
            "San Pedro de Atacama",
            "Tocopilla",
            "María Elena"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
`;
var json = JSON.parse(str);
var selRegiones = $('#regiones');
var selProvincias = $('#provincias');
var selComunas = $('#comunas');
var jsonRegiones = json.regiones;
var regionesOptions = "";

$.each(jsonRegiones, function(k, v) {
  regionesOptions += `<option value="${k}">${v.NombreRegion}</option>`;
});
  selRegiones.append(regionesOptions);

$(selRegiones).on('change', function() {

  selProvincias.find("option:not(:first)").remove();
  selComunas.find("option:not(:first)").remove();
  var provinciasOptions = "";
  var jsonProvincias = jsonRegiones[this.value].provincias;
  
  $.each(jsonProvincias, function(k, v) {
    $.each(v, function(provincia, comuna) {
      provinciasOptions += `<option value="${k}">${provincia}</option>`;
    });
  });

  selProvincias.append(provinciasOptions);
  
});

$(selProvincias).on('change', function() {

  selComunas.find("option:not(:first)").remove();
  var indexRegion = selRegiones.find(":selected").val();
  var keyProvincia = selProvincias.find(":selected").text();
  var arrComunas = jsonRegiones[indexRegion].provincias[this.value][keyProvincia];
  var comunasOptions = "";
  $.each(arrComunas, function(k, v) {
    comunasOptions += `<option value="${k}">${v}</option>`;
  });
  
  selComunas.append(comunasOptions);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="regiones">
  <option value="-1">--Seleccione Región--</option>
</select>
<br />
<select id="provincias">
  <option value="-1">--Seleccione Provincia--</option>
</select>
<br />
<select id="comunas">
  <option value="-1">--Seleccione Comunas--</option>
</select>
```

> #### PD
>
> Si te observas en los bucles verás que dentro de ellos se crean los `option` en una variable y luego se agregan una sola vez todos juntos.
>
> Considera implementar esa práctica cuando tengas que actualizar el DOM con elementos que van a obtenerse dentro de un bucle. Es mucho mejor concatenar y actualizar el DOM una sola vez que actualizarlo `n` veces en cada iteración.

Comment: Gracias lo adapte a mi código y funcionó.

Comment: Oiga una consulta, me fije que el valor que toma el select de las comunas es 0 luego de enviar a través de un form, pienso que es por esta linea, `$.each(arrComunas, function(k, v){ comunasOptions += `<option value="${k}">${v}</option>`;});` por esas variables k, v, que no toman el valor real del select de las comunas. Que si por ejemplo selecciono, _Valparaíso,_ su valor debería ser _Valparaíso_ y no 0

Comment: @M4uriXD eso es porque se le asigna como `value` el valor del índice que tienen en el array: `0,1,2...` si quieres que sea `Valparaíso` puedes poner el código así: `$.each(arrComunas, function(k, v){ comunasOptions += <option value="${v}">${v}</option>;});`  dado que luego de las comunas no hay dependencias puedes hacerlo, pero en los otros casos no, porque para las dependencias se usa ese índice para encontrar otros datos.

Comment: Gracias!!, es que tenia un buscador que filtraba los registros de una tabla por comuna, y me dejo de funcionar por ese valor que mencione, como arrojaba 0. Ahora quedó solucionado.

Comment: Ok, @M4uriXD. Se hizo así por conveniencia, para encontrar más fácil los otros valores dependientes por sus índices. Aunque en un entorno de bases de datos por ejemplo, lo más común es poner ahí un índice numérico precisamente que sería el id del elemento en la BD y usarlo como filtro. Es más rápido y es más seguro, porque los datos alfanuméricos son más susceptibles a errores de codificación, espacios en blanco, etc. En ese caso el `id` tendría que estar también en el JSON y se pondría como `value` en el `option` de los elementos.

Answer (score 1):

Comparto si alguien lo puede mejorar

```js
fetch('https://www.mafcom.cl/chile.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(json) { 
  
  let option; 
  let regiones = document.querySelector('#regiones');
  let provincias = document.querySelector('#provincias');
  let comunas = document.querySelector('#comunas'); 
  /// cargando regiones
       option += '<option> selecciona región</option>';
      for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) { // recorrido por las regiones
       option += '<option>' + json[i]["region"] +'</option>';
    }  
  regiones.innerHTML = option;   // inserando opciones

  regiones.addEventListener('change', (event) => { //escuchando opcion de region
  provincias.innerHTML = "";  
  option =""; 
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) { // recorriendo regiones
      if(json[i]["region"]==regiones.value){ // encontrar coincidencia
        let pro = json[i]["provincias"];  
            option += '<option> selecciona provincia</option>';
        for (var x = 0; x < pro.length; x++) { //recorriendo provincias
          option += '<option>' + pro[x]["name"] +'</option>'; 
          // ingresando botnes
        }
      }
      provincias.innerHTML = option; 
    }
});
  //escuchando opcion de provincias
  provincias.addEventListener('change', (event) => { 
    comunas.innerHTML = option;
    option ="";
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      if(json[i]["region"]==regiones.value){ 
        let pro = json[i]["provincias"];
        for (var x = 0; x < pro.length; x++) { 
          if(pro[x]["name"]==provincias.value){
          let com = pro[x]["comunas"];    
            option += '<option> selecciona comuna </option>';
            for (var z = 0; z < com.length; z++) {  
               option += '<option>' + com[z]["name"] +'</option>';
            } 
          comunas.innerHTML = option;  
          }
        }
        
      }
    }
});
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Regiones, provincias y cuidades de Chile</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck mb-3 pt-4 text-center">
    <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Localidades de Chile</h4>
        <p>Con la información actualizada de las regiones.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
         <h3>Selección</h3>
          <select id="regiones" class="form-control" required="required" name="regiones"></select>
          <br>
          <select id="provincias" class="form-control" required="required" name="provincia"></select>
           <br>
          <select id="comunas" class="form-control" required="required" name="comunas"></select>  

            <div class="resultado"></div> 
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  
  
 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido Miguel. Buena respuesta. Además de lo que comentaste en el código, creo que estaría mucho mejor aún si describieras muy brevemente lo que hace o cómo o en qué se diferencia de donde partió la pregunta, de modo que alguien que no sepa hacerlo tenga un pantallazo de la idea general